# I am trying to work on R using Azure ML Studio Notebook. But while installing and importing packages i am facing some challenges

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to install the some packages in Azure ML studio R notebook.

Upon typing `library(dplyr)` I get the error that

> package or namespace load failed for ‘dbplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Can anyone suggest on how to install and load packages here just like RStudio
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyIV7.png)

Comment: Can you try `install.packages("dbplyr", dependencies =TRUE)`, close your workbook and reopen it and try again.

Comment: @stevec i tried this but i am still facing a similar challenge: 'Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.2 is required'

Comment: Can you try the same again but for dplyr (as opposed to dbplyr): `install.packages("dbplyr", dependencies =TRUE)`

Comment: Whenever I get that sort of error, usually reinstalling packages then closing and reopening the R session fixes it 90% of the time

Comment: @stevec It worked for me after restarting the session! Thanks.